# Increase size of overall appearance in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

How to increase the size of overall appearance in Ubuntu 18.04. Consider the following screenshots with low appearance as shown below

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "low appearance"?

Comment: I mean lower in size of appearance, font and every thing.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to change? The screenshot looks fine to me.

Comment: @pomsky In concise, I want zooming the total screen..... I feel all are very low in size.

Comment: Then go to Settings > Devices > Displays and try choosing a different Resolution.

Answer (score 5):

The size of your desktop is primarily determined by your display resolution. You could increase the size of your desktop by lowering the resolution ("**Settings - Devices - Display**", **Resolution**). However, you should run at the highest resolution you have available, because that will provide you the best display quality.

Once you decided on your display resolution (choose the highest you can that works well), there are two ways to increase the desktop appearance.

- In **Settings - Devices - Displays**, you find a **scaling factor** if you are using a monitor that supports highDPI resolution. This allows you to scale the desktop by whole numbers. This setting is mainly aimed at accommodating high resolution displays.
- In Tweaks (you may need to install Gnome Tweaks, because it is not installed by default on Ubuntu), you find, on the "**Fonts**" tab, a "**scaling factor**", which allows to scale fonts of the user interface. Interface elements will also adapt to the changing font sizes, and thus give your desktop elements a larger appearance if you increase font size.

You should be able to find a combination of these settings that pleases you.

*Note* Enlarging the font size using the scaling factor will cause the accessibility icon to appear in your status bar. To turn that one off again, you can install the extension "Remove accessibility"

Comment: I meant "Resolution" is found in "Settings -> Devices -> Screen Display". Not sure about the scaling factor though, couldn't find it anywhere is Settings. Of course the is font-scaling option in Tweaks, under "Fonts".

Comment: "Scale" for me is the next line under "Resolution" on the "Displays" setting screen. "Screen display" will depend on your configuration. On my laptop it says "Built-in display". So we probably should stick with "Settings - Devices -  Display" which will lead any user to the Display settings screen, where one or more displays may be listed.

Comment: Yeah, probably the scaling factor option is disabled in my case due hardware limitation or something like that.

Comment: Will be available only for HighDPI screens - will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **settings** -> **Universal Access** -> **Large Text [ON]**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix I found:

**Appearance > Settings > Window Scaling - Make it 2x**

Works for resolution 2880x1800 (2.8k), 16:10 aspect ratio, XUbuntu in Vbox.

Tip: If you're having trouble setting a higher resolution or your screen goes black while doing so, increase the virtual memory for your VM in the VBox settings.